# Ruby TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to find if there is `mango/cc:` in my `data`  and if its there update its value to `new_version`, if its not there add `mango/cc:#{new_version}`

My `data`

```
{"product"=>"fruit", "id"=>"alpha", "details"=>{"SS"=>["mango/aa:50", "mango/cc:287_457_51.0.0"]}}
```

Code:

```
  new_version = "287_457_53.0.0"
  var1 = data['details']['SS'].select{|x| x.start_with?('mango/cc:')}
  if var1.empty?
    data['details'] << "mango/cc:#{new_version}"
  else
    data['details'].delete(var1)
    data['details'] << "mango/cc:#{new_version}"
    puts data
```

Current Output:

```
`[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
```

Expected Output:

```
{"product"=>"fruit", "id"=>"alpha", "details"=>{"SS"=>["mango/aa:50", "mango/cc:287_457_53.0.0"]}}
```

Comment: I don't get the same error with this code. Are you sure you posted corrrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it should work:

```
data={"product"=>"fruit", "id"=>"alpha", "details"=>{"SS"=>["mango/aa:50", "mango/cc:287_457_51.0.0"]}}
puts "Before: #{data}"
new_version = "287_457_53.0.0"
var1 = data['details']['SS'].select{|x| x.start_with?('mango/cc:')}
if var1.empty?
  data['details']['SS'] << "mango/cc:#{new_version}"
else
  data['details']['SS'].delete(var1.first)
  data['details']['SS'] << "mango/cc:#{new_version}"
end
puts "After: #{data}"

#=> Before: {"product"=>"fruit", "id"=>"alpha", "details"=>{"SS"=>["mango/aa:50", "mango/cc:287_457_51.0.0"]}}
#=> After: {"product"=>"fruit", "id"=>"alpha", "details"=>{"SS"=>["mango/aa:50", "mango/cc:287_457_53.0.0"]}}
```

There are several errors:

```
 var1 is an array
 data ['details'] is hash table
 "mango / cc: # {new_version}" is a string
```

You should add ['SS'] to delete the key (string) "mango / cc: # {new_version}" remembering that var1 is an array and not a string

Answer (score 0):

I think that the error is because var1 is an array, so your code must be something like:

```
new_version = "287_457_53.0.0" 
var1 = data['details']['SS'].select{|x| x.start_with?('mango/cc:')}
if var1.empty?
  data['details'] << "mango/cc:#{new_version}"
else
  data['details'].delete(var1.first)
  data['details'] << "mango/cc:#{new_version}"
  puts data
```

Just changing the param in `data['details'].delete` method